# How do I save the data in the order in a binary file using python?

Tags: python, data-structures, binary, queue

I want an optimized way to save the binary data in a file by splitting it into 4 parts. The problem is that when I get the data from the queue, it will save it in an unorganized way.

> Note: this is a sample of binary data. The binary file is much bigger
> than this.

```
import multiprocessing

queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue3 = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue4 = multiprocessing.Queue()

data = [b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00', b'\x10JFIF', b'\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00',
        b'H\x00H\x00\x00', b'\xff\xdb\x00C\x00', b'\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05',
        b'\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06', b'\x07\x07\x06\x08\n', b'\x10\n\n\t\t', b'\n\x14\x0e\x0f\x0c']

data2 = [b'\x10\x17\x14\x18\x18', b'\x17\x14\x16\x16\x1a', b'\x1d%\x1f\x1a\x1b', b'#\x1c\x16\x16 ',
         b", #&'", b')*)\x19\x1f', b'-0-(0', b'%()(\xff', b'\xdb\x00C\x01\x07', b'\x07\x07\n\x08\n']
data3 = [b'\x13\n\n\x13(', b'\x1a\x16\x1a((', b'(((((', b'(((((', b'(((((', b'(((((', b'(((((', b'(((((',
         b'(((((', b'(((((']
data4 = [b'(((((', b'(((\xff\xc2', b'\x00\x11\x08\x04L', b'\x029\x03\x01"', b'\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03',
         b'\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00', b'\x1c\x00\x01\x00\x02', b'\x03\x01\x01\x01\x00',
         b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04']


def put_data(data, data2, data3, data4):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i < 10:
            queue1.put(data[i])
            queue2.put(data2[i])
            queue3.put(data3[i])
            queue4.put(data4[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            break


def get_data():
    i = 0
    with open("myTest2.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            if i < 10:
                content = queue1.get()
                f.write(content)
                content = queue2.get()
                f.write(content)
                content = queue3.get()
                f.write(content)
                content = queue4.get()
                f.write(content)
                i = i + 1
                # print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=put_data(data, data2, data3, data4))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data())

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Why not just add all the records to a single queue?

Comment: because it is huge data and I need it split into 4 parts therefore the code above is just a sample.@milck

Comment: In case you save all parts to the same file or to the same storage medium which sense makes it to use multiprocessing?

Comment: it is a big project I'm trying to download 10 GB. in order to improve the speed of download I will use multiprocess. the above code is just a sample.@Claudio

Comment: Write each part to a separate file and then merge them when you're done. Alternatively, if you know the specific starting index of each part you're downloading, and you know the total file size, allocate a file of that size and write to those various indexes as the data comes in. Definitely don't read from 4 queues in this manner; read from the queues each in their own thread, and have them write to a single disk-I/O thread to avoid problems in the output file. Take lessons from torrenting software, as they solve this problem in a very general way.